# How pass {"encryptedData":"hgsfksjskjhkjv/hjgsgk/ksjghsfjghdskhfhj/"} in requestbody with karate

Tags: json, encryption

I have created a karate framework in which i was trying to pass the requestbody which has {"encryptedData":"hgsfksjskjhkjv/hjgsgk/ksjghsfjghdskhfhj/"} but am getting the error as below in response

But when trying to pass this value in requestbody its taking as \ along with / in body and throwing as errror json unmarshall.

help me if have any solution
its taking request as below
{"name":"morpheushhjjhjhhj\/jbbjcjdvffvv\/fgrgssvvgwr","job":"leader"}

Comment: From above it is not clear what you are doing, what you are getting and what you are expecting. The "errror" doesn't seem a copy from what you get on the screen either.